# Split Multilingual String into words c#

Tags: c#, regex, multilingual, split

I'm using  return `Regex.Split(s, @"\W")` to split string into words.

my input string is 怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢？[Pregnant with twins, natural delivery or caesarean section is good].

its working fine for english but when it comes to Japanese or Chinese it fails.[just splits into

```
Pregnant with twins
,
natural delivery or caesarean section is good
```

]

it should split into

```
Pregnant 
with 
twins
natural 
delivery 
or 
caesarean
section 
is 
good
```

is there a way in c# to do it.

please let me know.

Comment: if `怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢？[Pregnant with twins, natural delivery or caesarean section is good]` this is the input what is the expected output?

Comment: @Manish what is your expected output for the Japanese/Chinese part?

Comment: expected out put is ..words from japanese text.. like 1) Pregnant 2) with 3) twins 4) natural .....ect..ect

Comment: So the English words you put beside them are just translations, not part of the actual input.

Comment: @Manish if input is `怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢` you expecting output as 怀了双胞胎 and 顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢 ?

Comment: @SinaIravanian yes..thats only translation.

Comment: @Damith - i can not explain the out put in Japanese as i dont know the language..i have explained it in english..i want to have words pulled out of Japanese text..and the split is not working..

Answer (score 0):

As per your reply to one of the comments, that Chinese sentence what you have mentioned has two words. As words are separated by space, the given string "怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢" has unicode chars but unable to identify what is that separator character. But just tried in the usual way with that separator present in your string. Copied and pasted that between words character. It worked.

```
    string yourString = @"怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢";

    string[] splitted = Regex.Split(yourString, "，");

    foreach(string s in splitted)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(s + "\n");
    }
```

I am not sure whether it works for your other Japanese/Chinese sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but in traditional chinese very character in chinese is word itself do give a try to below and if it works for you.

```
string sentence = "怀了双胞胎，顺产还是剖腹产比较好呢？";
char[] chars = sentence.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char s in chars)
{
    sb.AppendLine(s.ToString()+"<br/>");
}
```